# raco exe error - dynamic-require error from (place) form in required module

Tags: racket, raco

I'm using Racket 6.8, and I'm getting a weird error when attempting to run an EXE created with `raco exe` when the project includes a `(place)` form in a module `require`d from the main module.

This can be reproduced with the following setup:

**main.rkt**

```
#lang racket
(require "place.rkt")
(module+ main
  (sync (place-dead-evt (start-place))))
```

**place.rkt**

```
#lang racket
(provide start-place)
(define (start-place)
  (place pch
    (displayln "Hello from a place!")))
```

If I run with the Racket interpreter, this works totally fine:

```
$ racket main.rkt
Hello from a place!
#<place-dead-evt>
```

If I create an EXE using `raco exe` however, I get the following:

```
$ raco exe -o place main.rkt
$ ./place
dynamic-require: unknown module
  module-name #<resolved-module-path:(submod '#%embedded:g2133:place place-body-1)>
#<place-dead-evt>
```

If I move the `(start-place)` function to main.rkt, the executable works correctly. However I'd prefer to not do that in my main project I'm working on.

Is there any way to invoke `raco exe` so that this works correctly? I tried including place.rkt with the `++lib` option, but that results in `raco` crashing.

Comment: You know. I think this is a bug. Would you mind reporting it?: https://github.com/racket/racket/issues

Comment: @LeifAndersen - sure, I added it at https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/1712. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I suspect the problem is how place is calling `dynamic-require`, but I am not familiar enough with the place library to know how to track down the bug. Thank you for opening an issue though. :)